# Append multiple JSON arrays and create a new consolidated JSON array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

In a file path, I have a few JSON files and I'm trying to consolidate them into one file using Newtonsoft.Json.

JSON1:

```
[
    {
        "name": "name1",
        "salary": 65000
    }, 
    {
        "name": "name2",
        "salary": 68000
    }
]
```

JSON2:

```
[
    {
        "name": "name3",
        "salary": 56000
    }, 
    {
        "name": "name4",
        "salary": 58000
    }
]
```

JSON3:

```
[
    {
        "name": "name5",
        "salary": 76000
    }, 
    {
        "name": "name6",
        "salary": 78000
    }
]
```

JSON4:

```
[
    {
        "name": "name7",
        "salary": 86000
    }, 
    {
        "name": "name8",
        "salary": 88000
    }
]
```

When I use the below code, I get the resulting file like below.

Code:

```cs
// List to store all the json objects
List<object> combinedJsonObjects = new List<object>();

// Load and append the JSON files
foreach (string filePath in jsonFilePaths)
{
    string jsonContent = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    object jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonContent);
    combinedJsonObjects.Add(jsonObject);
}

// Serialize the appended JSON objects
string combinedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(combinedJsonObjects, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

// save JSON file
string combinedJsonFilePath = @"C:\filePath\new.json";
File.WriteAllText(combinedJsonFilePath, combinedJson);
```

Result:

```
[
    [
        {
            "name": "name1",
            "salary": 65000
        }, 
        {
            "name": "name2",
            "salary": 68000
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "name": "name3",
            "salary": 56000
        },
        {
            "name": "name4",
            "salary": 58000
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "name": "name5",
            "salary": 76000
        },
        {
            "name": "name6",
            "salary": 78000
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "name": "name7",
            "salary": 86000
        },
        {
            "name": "name8",
            "salary": 88000
        }
    ]
]
```

But, when the multiple JSON files are consolidated I want the file to look like the below.

Desired Result:

```
[
    {
        "name": "name1",
        "salary": 65000
    },
    {
        "name": "name2",
        "salary": 68000
    },
    {
        "name": "name3",
        "salary": 56000
    },
    {
        "name": "name4",
        "salary": 58000
    },
    {
        "name": "name5",
        "salary": 76000
    },
    {
        "name": "name6",
        "salary": 78000
    },
    {
        "name": "name7",
        "salary": 86000
    },
    {
        "name": "name8",
        "salary": 88000
    }
]
```

Comment: It seems you need to append object contents. But you are trying add objects into a list. I think you need to create a model that covers the json content and deserialize the json content as model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try working with collection of `JObject`'s:

```
List<JObject> combinedJsonObjects = new List<JObject>();

// Load and append the JSON files
foreach (string filePath in jsonFilePaths)
{
    string jsonContent = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    object jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject[]>(jsonContent);
    combinedJsonObjects.AddRange(jsonObject);
}

// Serialize the appended JSON objects
string combinedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(combinedJsonObjects, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

// save JSON file
string combinedJsonFilePath = @"C:\filePath\new.json";
File.WriteAllText(combinedJsonFilePath, combinedJson);
```

Otherwise serializer will procees the whole JSON tree as a new element of the resulting collection (as you see in the resulting output).

Answer (score 1):

@GuruStron's answer is correct.

Another approach is you can read each JSON file and convert it as `JArray` (`JArray.Parse(jsonContent)`) and combine the `JArray`s into a single array via [`JArray.Merge()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Merge.htm).

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

List<object> combinedJsonObjects = new List<object>();
JArray jArray = new JArray();

// Load and append the JSON files
foreach (string filePath in jsonFilePaths)
{
    string jsonContent = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    jArray.Merge(JArray.Parse(jsonContent));
}

// Serialize the appended JSON objects
string combinedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jArray, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

// save JSON file
string combinedJsonFilePath = @"C:\filePath\new.json";
File.WriteAllText(combinedJsonFilePath, combinedJson);
```

Comment: [Sample Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XsxQaQ)